# Upload image to cloudinary without generating local file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloudinary

I am using [jdenticon](https://jdenticon.com/js-get-started/node-js.html) to generate user avatars on signup in a node/express app.

Running locally, I can do this by:

1. Generate identicon using [jdenticon](https://jdenticon.com/js-get-started/node-js.html)
2. Save file locally
3. Upload local file to [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com)

Here's how I do this

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'my-account-name',
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
});

// 1. Generate identicon

let jdenticon = require("jdenticon"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    size = 600,
    value = String(newUser.username),
    svg = jdenticon.toPng(value, size);
let file = "uploads/" + value + ".png";

// 2. Save file locally

fs.writeFileSync(file, svg);

// 3. Upload local file to cloudinary

let avatar = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file);

// Do stuff with avatar object
```

This works great for running my app locally. However, as I understand it, **I can't store images on Heroku** (if this is not the case then that would be great to know, and would simplify things massively), so I will need to save the generated identicon directly to cloudinary.

How can I upload the generated image (`svg = jdenticon.toPng(value, size);`) directly to cloudinary, without first saving?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[jdenticon.toPng](https://jdenticon.com/js-api/M_jdenticon_toPng.html) returns a buffer, I believe. And cloudinary's [upload_stream](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm#cloudinaryupload_stream) method accepts a buffer, so you should be able to just do ....

```
const data = jdenticon.toPng(value, size);
const options = {}; // optional

cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream(options, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log('saved .....');
  console.log(result);
}).end(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will test this out in the next few days.